# oraclehelper filldataset or another way to get SYS_REFCURSOR values at ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, oracle

To whom it may respond to,

We are developing our project using .net framework 4.0,Oracle 11gR2. The problem is that , we have to use Oraclehelper class, no other options, and we can't get SYS_REFCURSOR values . When googled , 
we have catched some pages writing about filldataset method of oraclehelper class, but this class doesn't exist in our Oraclehelper class.

Any workarounds, templates, examples etc. to get SYS_REFCURSOR values via Oraclehelper class?

Thank you for your concern,

Best Regards,

Kayhan YÜKSEL

Comment: when you are saying 'OracleHelper' class, are you referring to the SQLHelper clone created here? http://sourceforge.net/projects/oraclehelpernet/

Comment: this is an extract from a forum : " 
//Fill the datasets
OracleHelper.FillDataset(connString, sproc, CountyDataSet,
tableNames, oracleParam1, oracleParam2);

" the sender has given his/her email address for sending the helper class. We have sent him/her an email requesting the class.Any other clues? Thank you for your concern.

Comment: perfect, it is using ODP look at the below answer

Comment: tanging, where is the answer ?

Comment: @kayhan you should see the answer below, really all you need to do, when creating the parameter array, is have one that OracleDbType.RefCursor.  Since the OracleHelper just abstracts some of the boiler plate code, you can treat it as an extension of ODP and utilize the ODP logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming you are using the sourceforge.net/projects/oraclehelpernet  "oraclehelper" it is build ontop of ODP (ie Oracle.DataAccess.Client)
all you would need to do is:
(this is from http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/win.111/b28375/featRefCursor.htm)

```
String cmdTxt1 = "begin open :1 for select col1 from test; end;";
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(cmdTxt1, conn);
OracleParameter outRefPrm = cmd.Parameters.Add("outRefPrm",
      OracleDbType.RefCursor, DBNull.Value, ParameterDirection.Output);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // Execute the anonymous PL/SQL block
```

You can also look in %oracle_home%\client_1\odp.net\samples\4\RefCursor for 7 examples (this is when ODP is installed that is)

Since the OracleHelper just creates a wrapper around ODP, all you need to do is create the parameter as **OracleDbType.RefCursor** and pass it into the call (be it an execute non-query or datareader or whatnot)

now to do this via a procedure:

```
PROCEDURE Get1CurOut(p_cursor1 out refCursor) is 
      BEGIN 
      OPEN p_cursor1 for select * from emp; 
      END Get1CurOut;
```

and to the C#

```
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("Get1CurOut", con);
      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

      // Bind 
OracleParameter oparam = cmd.Parameters.Add("refcursor", OracleDbType.RefCursor);
  oparam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

      try 
      {
        // Execute command; Have the parameters populated
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        // Create the OracleDataAdapter
        OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);

        // Populate a DataSet with refcursor1.
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "refcursor1", (OracleRefCursor)(cmd.Parameters["refcursor1"].Value));

        // Print out the field count the REF Cursor
        Console.WriteLine("Field count: " + ds.Tables["refcursor1"].Columns.Count);
      }
```

this is lifted (with slight modification) from  %oracle_home%\client_1\odp.net\samples\4\RefCursor\sample1.cs

here is an (untested) OracleHelper example:

```
string connectionString = "User Id=scott;Password=tiger;Data Source=oracle";
CommandType commandType  = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
string commandText = "Get1CurOut";

OracleParameter oparam = cmd.Parameters.Add("refcursor", OracleDbType.RefCursor);
      oparam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;



 OracleDataReader reader;

        reader = OracleHelper.ExecuteReader(connectionString, commandType, commandText, oparam) ;

        // show the first row
        reader.Read();

        // Print out SCOTT.EMP EMPNO column
        Console.WriteLine("EMPNO: {0}", reader.GetDecimal(0));

        // Print out SCOTT.EMP ENAME column
        Console.WriteLine("ENAME: {0}", reader.GetString(1));
```

Comment: so, can we call stored procedures that have ref_cursor as output using this method?

Comment: @kayhan, exactly!  I do it all the time, you can do it via a function or procedure (I will ammend above to show example of procedure)

Comment: @kayhan, I changed the example to be based on sample1 from sample5 (sample5 actually used a function and thus not what you asked for!)

Comment: seemed that our .net developer used helper class from http://www.koders.com/csharp/fidDA38503BC16C71A9B61EABEC7A18F24C25C97243.aspx?s=mdef%3Adataset

Comment: @kayhan, it appears they are the same (comments and all).  I have added an OracleHelper example with a dataReader above based on the ODP (which that link also uses) sample1.cs

Comment: Thank you very much, very nice examples. Thanks again.

Comment: I have modified your code to get 2 params for user auth sample, trying to add the code, can't -1400 chars left. Way to add code here?

Comment: @kayhan, sorry I did not see this comment, can you edit your initial question with the addition code?  if that doesn't work let me know